# How to use `Word.run(function (context) {` in Office `Dialog API`

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I am developing with `Word AddIn`, I want to use  `Word.run(function (context) {` in `Dialog API`, but I always get exception `general exception` with internal server error. There is no additional message.

Error:

> Debug info: {"code":"GeneralException","message":"An internal error has occurred."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Word.run inside the dialog.

The `messageParent` function is one of only two Office APIs that can be called in the dialog box. The other is `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported`. The messageParent function can only be called on a page with the same domain (including protocol and port) as the host page.

I got this info from the documentation: [Use the Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)